# Need help:- Want solution for Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to String

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting error

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to String

My code is

```
String str1= drive.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='name']")).sendKeys(CustomerName);
```

Comment: You've posted a single line of code, totally out of context, made up of unknown method or function calls, and expect us to explain it? You didn't even bother to include a language tag. When you created your account here, it was suggested that you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to better understand this site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.

Comment: I am passing CustomerName from excelsheet

Comment: I am sorry Ken and Wai ..... acutally i dont what i have to enter in the tags field. I am going through the site for details but not getting what i have to write there. Can you help me i am totally new to this forum......

Comment: I am working in eclipse with java 1.7

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.sendKeys()` has no return... aka `void`. You are assigning the return of `.sendKeys()`, which doesn't exist, to a string, `str1`.

If you remove the assignment

```
drive.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='name']")).sendKeys(CustomerName);
```

you will no longer receive the error. Because you didn't explain what your code is supposed to do, I'm not sure what you were attempting when you assigned `str1` so maybe this is a good enough answer or maybe there's something else you were trying to do that is still missing.

Comment: Thank you JeffC. I was trying to to take the text out of excel sheet and assign it to string so that i can compare it . Now i changed my code and taking all the elements in webelement..... the error has definitely gone now.

Comment: Great. If this, or any answer, was useful, please upvote it. If any answer answered your question, please accept it.